# How to get the Iris Data set to plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Just doing the basic data set from the examples in the R-Graph-gallery, not sure why I can't get anything to plot correctly.

I searched around and some posts said to install 'extrafonts' but that also isn't possible:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - r-extrafonts
```

iris plot error:

[image]

Using *theme_ipsum* from [hrbrthemes package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=hrbrthemes)

Comment: What exactly did you try to copy and paste? What OS and R version are you running? Does it work without `theme_ipsum()`?

Answer (score 0):

You perhaps want to figure out which of your Windows fonts are not present or present in a location that R is not expecting. Here's how to find the installed and accessible PDF fonts  known to R. I'm working with PDF fonts because you mentioned something that might be a reference to an R package named "extrafont". There is no CRAN -sited package named 'r-extrafonts'.

```
 names(pdfFonts())
 [1] "serif"                "sans"                 "mono"                 "AvantGarde"          
 [5] "Bookman"              "Courier"              "Helvetica"            "Helvetica-Narrow"    
 [9] "NewCenturySchoolbook" "Palatino"             "Times"                "URWGothic"           
[13] "URWBookman"           "NimbusMon"            "NimbusSan"            "URWHelvetica"        
[17] "NimbusSanCond"        "CenturySch"           "URWPalladio"          "NimbusRom"           
[21] "URWTimes"             "ArialMT"              "Japan1"               "Japan1HeiMin"        
[25] "Japan1GothicBBB"      "Japan1Ryumin"         "Korea1"               "Korea1deb"           
[29] "CNS1"                 "GB1"
```

I'm on a Linux box so yours will undoubtedly be different. The first three will be the defaults. You can examine it more carefully to see which font is likely to be askew or missing:

```
 pdfFonts()[['serif']]$family
[1] "Times"

 pdfFonts()[['serif']]
$family
[1] "Times"

$metrics
[1] "Times-Roman.afm"      "Times-Bold.afm"       "Times-Italic.afm"     "Times-BoldItalic.afm"
[5] "Symbol.afm"          

$encoding
[1] "default"

attr(,"class")
[1] "Type1Font"
```